# Tradução a melhorar quando gratificação expira

Tags: bug, tradução, localização

Nessa pergunta foi oferecida uma gratificação:

[Javascript/Nodejs setInterval com início programado, estilo cron simples](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4940/javascript-nodejs-setinterval-com-inicio-programado-estilo-cron-simples)

Nesse momento seu tempo já expirou e está no período de tolerância para o autor da pergunta gratificar alguém. O texto que está aparecendo é esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Problemas

- `que terminou em 1 hora atrás.`. Eu diria que o correto é `que terminou há/faz 1 hora [atrás].` Deve ter um `há` no lugar do `em`, ou talvez um `faz`. Também tem o `atrás` que talvez seja redundante. Sinceramente não tenho certeza de como deve ficar, apenas sei que está estranho, essas são minhas sugestões.
- `termina em em 22 horas`. Tem um `em` a mais. Essa eu tenho certeza :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Toda a tradução soa um pouco estranho, mas para tentar chegar a uma sugestão que resulte tanto para português de Portugal como Brasil, eu sugeria a seguinte rectificação:

> Esta pergunta tinha uma gratificação valendo +50 pontos da reputação de Emerson Rocha Luiz que terminou 1 hora atrás. O período de tolerância termina em 22 horas.

### Pontos chave que foram alterados:

- Hora em que terminou

  > ...que terminou em 1 hora atrás.

  Retirado o `em`, visto estar claramente a mais.

  <sup>**Nota:** Em Portugal seria `que terminou há 1 hora.`</sup>
- Ponto ou Ponto(s)

  > ponto(s)

  Que seja do meu conhecimento, não existem gratificações de 1 ponto, pelo que a excessiva precaução ao usar-se `ponto(s)` na forma de preparar a palavra para singular e plural é completamente desnecessário.
- Reputação e Nome de utilizador

  > de reputação de Emerson Rocha Luiz

  Não sei como é no Brasil, mas `de ... de ...` é mesmo estranho a ler.
  Salvo alguma questão que se prenda com os utilizadores Brasileiros, deveria ser:
  `da reputação de nome-de-utilizador`
  Ou seja, estamos a retirar pontos à reputação do utilizador X.

  Usaria `pontos de reputação` se ao dizermos `pontos da reputação` acharem que tem uma conotação negativa no âmbito social.
- *Typo* no período de tolerância

  > termina em em 22 horas

  Claramente o `em` a mais.

Comment: `Nota: Em Portugal seria que terminou à 1 hora.` não seria `Nota: Em Portugal seria que terminou há 1 hora.`?

Comment: Só se deve usar `há` quando o mesmo pode ser trocado por `existir`, `acontecer`, ou `fazer`. Ver [Porto Editora: há ou à?](http://www.portoeditora.pt/espacolinguaportuguesa/duvidas-da-lingua-portuguesa/detalhe-duvidas-lp/ver/ha-ou-a-?id=5183&langid=1). _(copy&paste do comentário na resposta do mgibsonbr)_

Comment: Mas o @bfavaretto é o mais entendido _(e chato :D)_ com esta questão... eu sou um leigo :P

Comment: então, não dá pra trocar por `faz`? `terminou faz 1 hora` == `terminou há 1 hora`

Comment: @Math De qualquer forma, penso que pelo tempo verbal em que a frase está, o correcto é usar `à` e não `há`.

Comment: `não existem gratificações de 1 ponto` essa passou despercebido por mim, realmente, a frase inteira está muito mal traduzida

Comment: @Math Não sou especialista, mas dado que a palavra `terminou` está no passado, eu diria que `à` é a utilização correcta! De qualquer maneira alguém de línguas pode ajudar com esta duvida.

Comment: vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13136/discussion-between-math-and-zuul)

Comment: achei mais um bug! cadê o `ã` no texto do comentário acima? :P

Comment: "Nota: Em Portugal seria que terminou à 1 hora." se for "à 1 hora da manhã" ou "à 1 hora da tarde" (i.e. hora exata) aí concordo, mas não conheço suficiente do português de Portugal pra afirmar com certeza... E quanto a usar "do" antes do nome do usuário, funciona se seu gênero for masculino, mas não creio que devíamos ter isso por padrão. "de" fica um pouco estranho, sim, mas aceitável na minha opinião (mas gostei do "da reputação" em vez de "de reputação"). No mais, concordo com sua sugestão de tradução.

Comment: Math e mgibsonbr estão certos, é **há uma hora** (no sentido de uma hora atrás). Não tem diferença de regra desse tipo entre o português de Portugal e o do Brasil.

Comment: @bfavaretto [mas... mas... mas... ok](http://i.imgur.com/mygRwp7.gif) :(

Comment: @Zuul Já te falei disso uma vez, não sei se você lembra: aqui no Brasil, a pronúncia de todos esses a/à/há é a mesma. Em Portugal, que eu saiba, a pronúncia muda. Por exemplo: "vou à Europa" tem um A mais aberto do o A de "a Europa é bonita". E o "há" também é aberto, por isso suponho que sua confusão tenha influência disso.

Comment: @bfavaretto Já fiz a **revisão** <--- :D à resposta, penso que agora ficou bem!

Comment: Já fiz minha **análise** :D, agora está correto. +1 de novo

Comment: Já consertei minha **pergunta** :D, tinha cometido o mesmo equívoco do Zuul, agora ficou melhor.

Comment: Em PT_PT ou PT_BR as regras do **PORTUGUÊS** são as mesmas @bfavaretto. São é utilizadas de formas diferentes. Como o "estou ficando" e "estou a ficar" as duas formas são corretas em Português, mas uma mas utilizada no BR outra em PT.

Comment: Além disso não é uma regra e sim um tempo verbal. Que vem do verbo "haver" e por isso é que "à" está incorreto.

Comment: Sim @JorgeB., concordo 100%. Dei a entender outra coisa? O que eu estava dizendo era uma hipótese (fonética) para explicar por que é comum os portugueses usarem "à" por "há" (é menos comum no Brasil, embora eu também já tenha visto ocorrer).

Answer (score 2):

Minha sugestão:

> que terminou 1 hora atrás

Alternativamente:

> que terminou há 1 hora

mas prefiro a primeira opção.

"faz 1 hora" também faz sentido, mas ["a 1 hora" não](http://www.usinadetextos.com.br/dicas/a-uma-hora-ha-uma-hora-a-uma-hora). E se fizesse, não levaria crase, pois [crase](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crase) é "a" (preposição) + "a" (artigo). Compare:

> que terminou ao meio-dia
>
> que terminou à meia-noite
>
> que terminou à 1 hora e meia da tarde

E se fosse no futuro:

> Eles irão a uma hora qualquer.
>
> Eles irão a um minuto qualquer.

(i.e. não tem artigo "a"/"o", portanto não tem crase)

Comment: Também prefiro a primeira opção. E obrigado pela aula de português, eu falei `a` quando na verdade era `há`, estou cada vez pior nisso, rsrs.. Ainda bem que tem um [SE de português](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64172/portuguese-language) a caminho :)

Answer (score 2):

São 2 strings diferentes, no sistema de tradução:

A primeira era:

> Esta pergunta tinha uma gratificação valendo $Pontos$ ponto(s) de reputação de $Usuario$ que terminou em $Tempo$

E passou para:

> $Usuario oferecia $Pontos$ pontos de reputação como recompensa nesta pergunta, até $endDate$.

---

A segunda era:

> O período de tolerância termina em $TempoRestante$

Passou para:

> O período de tolerância termina $TempoRestante$

Comment: "O período de tolerância termina 1 hora" é assim que aparece? @Gabe?

Comment: Pelo que entendi está resolvido então, né? Não faltou colocar a tag `status-pronto`?